# Using lxml to retrieve both tag and subtag categories with unicode encoding

Tags: python, xml, unicode, lxml

I am attempting to use Collections.counter with lxml to count all the nouns and adjectives in an xml file, where the noun and adjective tags are written as follows:

```
<word id="2" start="7400" end="7411" tag="NN">Ministerien</word>
```

Where the tag="NN" denotes a noun. I would like to pull only these out, and add them to a counter, but I am having difficulty doing so. I can currently pull out all the words and count them, but cannot find a way in lxml to only take certain subtags.

Here is the current relevant code.

```
context = etree.iterparse(xmlFile)
counter = collections.Counter()
for action, elem in context:
    if elem.tag == "word":
      counter[elem.text] += 1
print counter.most_common(10)
```

Comment: Do you want the counter to have only two keys - `Noun` and `Adjective` ?

Comment: no, each word should have its own key. there are many other types in the files, and i only want the nouns and adjectives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elem.attrib` returns a dictionary of key:value pairs, where the keys are the properties/attributes for that xml element and value is the value of that particular attribute.

You can use that and check whether the attribute `tag`'s is either noun or adjective.

Example -

```
context = etree.iterparse(xmlFile)
counter = collections.Counter()
for action, elem in context:
    if elem.tag == "word" and (elem.attrib.get('tag') in ['NN','AD']): #AD I just used for adjective, use whatever is correct.
      counter[elem.text] += 1
print counter.most_common(10)
```

---

Example/Demo -

I have an xml file like -

```
<root>
<word id="2" start="7400" end="7411" tag="NN">Ministerien1</word>
<word id="2" start="7400" end="7411" tag="AD">Ministerien5</word>
<word id="2" start="7400" end="7411" tag="NN">Ministerien2</word>
<word id="2" start="7400" end="7411" tag="NN">Ministerien1</word>
<word id="2" start="7400" end="7411" tag="AD">Ministerien4</word>
<word id="2" start="7400" end="7411" tag="AD">Ministerien4</word>
<word id="2" start="7400" end="7411" tag="HF">Ministerien6</word>
<word id="2" start="7400" end="7411" tag="AD">Ministerien4</word>
<word id="2" start="7400" end="7411" tag="NN">Ministerien2</word>
<word id="2" start="7400" end="7411" tag="NN">Ministerien3</word>
</root>
```

Code -

```
In [18]: context = etree.iterparse('a.xml')

In [19]: counter = Counter()

In [20]: for action, elem in context:
   ....:     if elem.tag == "word" and (elem.attrib.get('tag') in ['NN','AD']):
   ....:         counter[elem.text] += 1

In [21]: counter
Out[21]: Counter({'Ministerien4': 3, 'Ministerien2': 2, 'Ministerien1': 2, 'Ministerien3': 1, 'Ministerien5': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now i am having a character encoding issue, where the characters with umlauts and other german-specific characters are not showing correctly. ex: u'B\xfcrgermeiser should be Übermeister. I assume this is from the parser not using utf-8 encoding. The file itself contains` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, so that is not the issue. Is there a way to change the encoding on the parser? I have looked on lxml.de and can't find anything (funny that a german made library doesn't deal with german well)

Comment: Yes, you can create your own parser and specify encoding for that , check out - http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html . Create the parser with the encoding you want and send it in as second argument to `parse()` function.